# Flagged comment as spam; nothing happens

Tags: support

I flagged this [attempt at sarcasm](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1124/did-does-the-shaolin-wooden-men-labyrinth-exist) by user Peter of The Corn as spam, because:

- It adds nothing to question (doesn't ask/help to clarify, etc)
- It doesn't help with answer
- It is essentially some sort of straw man / false generalization and is what they call a flame bait, thus inappropriate in Q/A site.

Can it get deleted by any chance, or comments like this are in place here?

Comment: Gone. We didn't honestly understand your reasons until this post.

Answer (score 2):

There are now reasons for flagging comments so you can explain your rationale without needing to post on meta about it.

[image]